# Como prevenir que uma aplicação .NET possa ser chamada mais de uma vez?

Tags: c#, .net

Se não quiser permitir que a aplicação rode mais de uma vez na mesma máquina, é possível proibir que outra chamada ocorra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O .NET tem infra que ajuda fazer isto:

```
Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName).Length > 1
```

Ou seja, você pode pegar se existe um executável com mesmo nome rodando. Se retornar uma lista com mais de 1, então já está rodando outra instância, aí você encerra a execução.

Porém se a pessoa renomear dá para burlar isso. Pode usar o nome que definiu e se ele renomear também não deixar rodar. Pode ter outras formas de burlar.

Também pode cria um [`Mutex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para impedir que outro igual esteja ativo, algo assim:

```
using System.Threading;

public class Program {
    static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "Nome que eu escolhi");
    static void Main() {
        if (!mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true)) return;
        //continua aqui
    }
}
```

Dá para fazer algo mais sofisticado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enviroment/MutexProcess.cs).

Comment: Os Mutex são compartilhados pelo sistema operacional ou pelo processo apenas? Como que outro processo irá saber que esse Mutex está reservado?

Comment: Há compartilhamento geral, por isso um processo consegue enxergar o que o outro criou.